# modern origin - gig

Tags: etymology

The historical meaning of the word **Gig** is:

> a light two-wheeled carriage pulled by one horse.
>
> a light, fast, narrow boat adapted for rowing or sailing.

However, in modern use, it refers to:

> a live performance by a musician or group playing popular or jazz music.

I am curious about this transformation. How did it go from the former to latter?

Comment: Gig: 
"job," originally in the argot of jazz musicians, attested from 1915 but said to have been in use c. 1905; of uncertain origin. As a verb, by 1939. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gig

Comment: I object to this question being labeled as duplicate. It is about the transformation of the word from latter to former meaning. @Josh

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thank you. But the two questions are very different. I believe it unjust to mark this as duplicate.

Comment: @Josh, if I wasn't clear enough; revert your duplicate badge.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: could it be related to the word 'jig' (also spelt 'gigue' in some uses as well as in French)?

Comment: This is a comment at best. The answer box is for researched material that can support a real answer.

Comment: Also, the possibility of derivation from _gigue_ is mentioned in the more complete answer at the marked duplicate posting.

Comment: Ah sorry. Duly noted.